# Why does an audio signal sound differently if we randomly flip gradients between each adjacent pair of samples?

Tags: acoustics, perception

Let's assume the samples of our audio signal are always in the interval `[-1,+1]`. When flipping all the samples (multiplying them by -1), listening to the sound makes me think that I listen to the original, unflipped sound (tested it with a recording of my voice). This **seems** to indicate that the sign of the gradient is irrelevant to human perception. However, if I randomly flip the **gradients** (not the sample value!) between all adjacent pairs of samples of the audio signal, I get a rather messy noise that still somewhat resembles my voice but is very distorted. I made sure that the "randomness" of flipping is manipulated in such a way that the values never leave the `[-1,+1]` interval.

Why does flipping the gradient of a sound randomly change the perception of an audio signal?

Comment: I suggest opening your sound files in an audio editor, and have a look at the waveforms. First have a look at the original, then have a look at the one where you "flipped" _all_ of the samples. Do the waveforms look different to you? If so, how? Now look at the one were you "randomly" flipped samples. Does that, perhaps, look qualitatively different from the other two?

Comment: @SolomonSlow Of course it looks different. But that's not a really satisfying explanation to why the percetion of the sound is different.

Comment: The signal-processing definition of "noise" is the difference between the signal you have, and the signal you wish you had. If you subtract, sample-by-sample, your "very distorted" signal from the original, the difference between them is the "noise" that you introduced.  If I had a stronger mathematical background, I could maybe talk about what the [Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_analysis) of that noise looks like, but sad to say,... I don't know how to do that. Hence, no actual "answer" from me.

Comment: Please include a picture of the signal, before and after flipping the gradient.

Answer (score 3):

Why would you expect the sound to be the same when you flip the sign of random samples?

Take a signal that is constant for example: The value of a sample more or less represents the position of the speaker at that time. In theory the speaker will not move over the whole duration (You will not hear anything). Flipping the sign of all samples will result in the same constant curve, just at a different position

[image]

However, when you randomly flip the sign of samples within the soundfile, you will create gradients between successive samples where the speaker will move and create a sound.

[image]

The same thing will happen to your soundfile that is not constant. Flipping all samples will create the same motion (just inverted) of the speaker and thus the same pressure waves. Flipping random samples will alter the value difference between neighboring samples and will make the speaker move a different amount than it should be.

Comment: For the third audio signal I did not flip the sign of the sample, but the sign of the gradient.

Comment: I misread your question, sorry. That is a good question indeed.
I would imagine that there is not a trivial relationship between the sound waves produced, and the quantity we called "gradient" here (really just the difference between two adjastend samples).
If you think about two examples that would have the same (absolute) "gradient":
1. A soundfile that is a line with a constant slope (sample values have the same positive "gradient" between them). 
2. A soundfile where the samples form a zig-zig-line, but with the exact same absolute "gradient" between the samples as the first soundfile.

Comment: Although they have the same absolute gradient between soundfiles, if you think about the pressure waves the speaker would produce, you would expect a difference:
For 1.: The speaker moves just with a constant speed in on direction, creating just 1 large (over- or under-) pressure wave.
For 2.: The zig-zag-motion of the speaker would definitely create multiple wave peaks.

Answer (score 2):

Whatever your audio processing algorithm is, try it on a simple sine wave (ie, one with a single fixed frequency and phase).  If the result doesn't remain a simple sine wave of the same frequency, then the input and output will sound different.

For your specific algorithms: 1) flipping the waveform will not change the frequency (or amplitude) of the sine wave. 2) Random flips based on the gradient change the output so it's no longer a sine wave, so it will sound different.

Overall, the focus on gradients and the shape of the waveform are somewhat of a misdirection when asking what something sounds like.  The reason for this (and the reason I suggest looking at sine waves) is that human hearing is largely based around hearing the sine wave components of a given sound.  Within those sine wave components, the absolute frequencies are important, the relative amplitudes are important, and nothing about the phases are very important it determining what something sounds like.  The reason this is helpful for understanding gradients (and shape of the waveform) is that gradients can change a lot based on the phases, so two things can sound the same and yet have very different gradients, which implies that the gradients (and the shape of the waveform) aren't the important factor in determining what something sounds like.  (And if you want to know whether things sound the same or different, you're much better off looking at the spectrum or spectrogram, which are tools for visualizing the sine wave components, than the waveform.  So even with the various algorithms you're looking at, I suggest plotting the spectrogram of your speech, before and after the algorithms are applied and you will be able to see the important differences, while not being misdirected by unimportant differences.)

Answer (score 2):

What you have done is essentially filtered out all the low frequency sound.  There used to be extended periods when the gradient tended to be the same sign, meaning that there was significant energy at periods much longer than the sampling interval.  By randomizing the sign of the change from sample to sample, you removed that energy (and added some at high frequency).  Your ear cares about the frequency content only.  You can change the waveform to something that looks totally different by keeping the frequency content the same but changing the phases of the constituent frequencies, and it will sound the same.  But you have messed with the spectrum.

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer of the question. But when I flip the phase of one of the harmonics, the sound does not change (although the waveform is quite different).
[image]

You can play with that here, html5 by Ruiz:
https://www.opus.unca.edu/html5/fourier/fourier16.html

(A small change in the amplitude of the harmonics is clearly audible.)